# RSI (repetitive-stress injuries) questions - on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I certainly thought this [question about wrist pain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62149/do-you-have-finger-wrist-pain-how-do-you-deal-with-that) was off-topic, given that the FAQ says *nothing* about health issues, but my flag was declined.

Am I mis-reading the FAQ? Is there any other meta-issue here? While I realize the question may be of *interest* to programmers, it would also apply to *anyone* who uses a computer extensively, not just programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was the one that dismissed the flag - at first look the question and answers did look like they were offering a "unique to programmers" perspective.

However, on looking again I can see that this is borderline at best.

Comment: Any chance I can get the lost flag weight back? :) Not exactly vital, just a minor annoyance, if it's not possible.

Comment: @Cyclops - probably not, sorry.

Comment: No worries, didn't think so, just had to check. :) At least the question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

I fail to see how either the question or any of the answers have any relevance to computer programmers as opposed to a secretaries, authors, graphic designers or anyone who regularly uses a mouse and keyboard for long periods.

Comment: In light of this question and your answer I've closed the question as "off topic".